# View state, new activity start

Tags: gwt, mvp

I use the [MVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-presenter) pattern in my project. According to it Place define view after a new Activity starts. In some cases when I have to save the content of some Text areas after change of Place. I think that it is not a good idea to put these text areas in Place, because they don't define business logic. To save them in View elements is not good either. How do I resolve this situation?

Answer (score 0):

GUI elements (GWT widgets) belong in Views. Why do you think otherwise?

Then your View interface (or is it Display?) can have getTextData()/setTextData() methods to retrieve data in your TextBox.